# Run report from activity form

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I created a report on tasks in Dynamics CRM 2013. After importing this report I noticed there is no 'Run Report' button in task forms (also in phonecall, appointment, etc. forms).

I only could run the report from activities list view.

Is there any possibility to add this button in CRM 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably **[this post](http://www.develop1.net/public/post/How-to-restore-a-hidden-button-on-the-CRM-2013-Command-Bar.aspx)** will help you, didn't try this approach for activities reports but for opportunities and custom entities it works well.

Comment: It pointed me to the right direction. With a short search I found [this post](http://mscrmshop.blogspot.de/2013/12/run-report-button-on-custom-entities.html) to edit the customizations.xml file. Thanks a lot.